# Finding brake parts

Tags: brakes, chevrolet, impala

I'm working on a 1963 Chevy Impala. I am rebuilding the drum brakes, but I can't seem to find all the parts-- some have gone missing over the years.

Is there anywhere to find all the internals in one kit, or do I have to piece together the self adjusters and all the other various hardware from other models?

If that's the case, are there other Chevy cars from the era that have identical brakes?

Thanks!

Edit to be more clear:

I don't need just a spring kit, I'm looking for the brake strut, the adjusters, etc.

Edit 2:

Apparently the struts and parking brake lever are no longer made. So I had to scour some sources for them. Oddly enough I did find the self-adjuster kits in the local store, as OEM aftermarket parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is an "all-in-one" or "combo" brake drum hardware kit. You can pick these up from most of the major parts stores. [Here is an example from RockAuto.com](http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=2429476&cc=1324505) with it's corresponding picture:

[image: Brake Hardware from RockAuto]

This should be enough for one axle. I'm not sure if front/back are the same, but I believe so. You can get the other bits and pieces (ie: self adjuster) from RockAuto.com as well, but would imagine you can pick them up from your major parts stores.

The Impala was built on the [GM "B" platform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GM_B_platform), which is a full-sized, rear wheel drive auto. Cars such as the Buick Wildcat, Oldsmobile Dynamic 88, and Pontiac Bonneville & Catalina models were based off the same platform. GM is renowned for cross breeding its fleet. I don't know exactly what years it spans, but would bet you will find the same exact brake drum kit covering several years. I will tell you it looks *very* familiar to me, as common to GM vehicles which I have worked on in the past. As for the Impala, it looks as though these same parts were used between 1959-1970. Why change it if it works?

Comment: @Paulster2-- thanks, but I have those kits. I'm looking for the hardware more so than just the springs. I need all the parts like the brake strut, the adjuster lever, the park brake lever, etc.

Comment: @user101289 ... gotcha. You are then looking for the parts which attach to the backing plate itself. I would bet you are going to have to piece those parts together. Google for vintage Chevrolet parts and you'll see a plethora of places which sell parts. I found the e-brake arm through a cursory search. I'm sure you'll see the other parts by searching for them.